# map<char[], char[]> in flex C++ doesn't compile

Tags: c++, dictionary, flex-lexer

I am working on flex (.lex file) in vmPlayer on linux, and I want to convert sass code to css code.
I want to work with a map of char arrays, to match variables in sass to their values. For some reason, I can not insert values to my map.

```
%{
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string>
   #include <map>
   #include<iostream>
   std::map<char[20], char[20]> dictionary;   //MY DICTIONARY,GOOD
%}
%%
s       dictionary.insert(std::pair<char[20], char[20]>("bb", "TTTT")); //PROBLEM
%%
```

it does not compile and gives me error:

```
hello.lex:30:84: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<char    
[20], char [20]>::pair(const char [3], const char [5])’
ine(toReturn);  dictionary.insert(std::pair<char[20], char[20]>("bb", 
"TTTT"));
```

In general, I am not sure what **C** libraries I can use easily on flex and which are more fishy using flex.
Is there a syntax problem?

Comment: This is C++ code, not C code. So you should tag your question as C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in the generated C++ code is that `pair(const char [3], const char [5])` (which is the size of your constant strings) has nothing to do with `pair(const char [20], const char [20])`. It is just *not* the same type.

3 solutions:

- add template arguments for char array sizes (EDIT: does not work, because it would still have to be the same sizes for all elements)
- use `char []` instead if you only have constants to insert
- or better & simpler & covers all cases: use `std::string` type, which accepts char arrays in its constructor.

like this:

```
%{
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string>
   #include <map>
   #include<iostream>
   std::map<std::string, std::string> dictionary;   //MY DICTIONARY,GOOD
%}
%%
s       dictionary.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>("bb", "TTTT"));
%%
```

Comment: it did work, but now I cant print it because it's waiting for char* --> fprintf(yyout, "%s",dictionary["bb"]); gives me error : **ello.lex:60:47: error: invalid cast from type ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::mapped_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to type ‘char*’
     fprintf(yyout, "%s",(char*)dictionary["bb"]);**

Comment: try `std::cout` which can print `std::string` or use `dictionary["bb"].c_str()` to get char contents.

Comment: mooly: use: dictionary["bb"].c_str()